# TexMaker, permanent changing of the path

Tags: macos, path

I just update my MacBook with the last OS, El Capitan. I follow all the suggestions ([link-1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/271221/texmaker-command-not-found-on-macos-el-capitan/271255#271255) and [link-2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/270717/texmaker-and-el-capitan-spinning-beachball-of-death)) in order to make TexMaker work in a proper way, but when I relaunch the application all the changes in the paths are back as the origin so I always have to specify `/Library/Tex/texbin` instead of `/usr/texbin`. How I can make this changes permanent?

There is a different setting in the terminal or system settings where I should specify the right path?

Comment: Please help us to help you by providing links to "all the suggestion" - so we know what you have & haven't tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I edit the settings opening the program as administrator.